# Show that if $a$ and $b$ have the same sign then $|a + b| = |a| + |b| $, and if $a$ and $b$ have opposite signs then $|a+b| < |a| + |b|$

Tags: solution-verification, absolute-value

I'm considering the different cases for $a$ and $b$

**Case 1)** $ a\geq 0$ and $ b\geq 0$

Given both terms are positive, $ a + b \geq 0 $
$$
|a+b| = a + b = |a| + |b|\\
$$

**Case 2)** $ a< 0$ and $ b< 0$

Given both terms are negative, $ a + b < 0 $
$$
|a+b| = -(a + b) = -a -b = |a| + |b|\\
$$

**Case 3)** $ a> 0$ and $ b< 0$

**Case 3a)** $ a + b \geq 0 $

Knowing that $ b < -b $ because $ b < 0 < -b $:
$$
|a+b| = a + b < a - b = |a| + |b|
$$
**Case 3b)** $ a + b \leq 0 $

Knowing that $ -a < a $ because $ -a < 0 < a $:
$$
|a+b| = -(a + b) = -a - b < a - b = |a| + |b|
$$

**Case 4)** $ a< 0$ and $ b> 0$

**Case 4a)** $ a + b \geq 0 $

Knowing that $ a < -a $ because $ a < 0 < -a $:
$$
|a+b| = a + b < -a + b = |a| + |b|
$$

**Case 4b)** $ a + b \leq 0 $

Knowing that $ -b < b $ because $ -b < 0 < b $:
$$
|a+b| = -(a + b) = -a -b < -a + b = |a| + |b|
$$

Is my proof correct?

I feel like it's somewhat incomplete as I'm not considering when either $a$ or $b$ are equal to zero in the cases 3 and 4.

Comment: It's very complicated. Try to do it comparing the squares of both sides, this will eliminate  the absolute values.

Comment: Since $0$ does not have a sign it is assumed that $a$ and $b$ are non-zero. Anyway $|a+b|=|a|+|b|$ when either $a$ or $b$ is $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dealing with absolute values, the general strategy is: if you can avoid the cases method, do it.

Here , we have a typical example of this strategy: as both expressions are non-negative numbers, we compare them by comparing their squares, using that $|x|^2=x^2\,$:
$$|a+b|^2=a^2+2ab+b^2,\enspace \text{ and }\enspace (|a|+|b|)^2=a^2+2|a||b|+b^2,$$
so that comparing $|a+b|$ and $|a|+|b|$ amounts to comparing $ab$ and $|a||b|=|ab|$, namely
$$|a+b| <|a|+|b|\iff  ab<|ab| \iff ab<0,$$
i.e., in ordinary language $a$ and $b$ have different signs.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Very clear. At the end of your answer I could also say that it's true because for all x, $ x < |x| $, right?

Comment: If $x$ is negative, yes. It was implicit in my presentation

Answer (score 2):

*Something similar to yours:*

The first part was, indeed, easy.

> For the second part:

Without loss of generality, take $|a|>|b|~~~~~~~~~(*)$

- $a>0, b<0 \overset{(*)}\implies a+b>0$. Then, indeed, $\underbrace{|a+b|}_{=a+b}  < \underbrace{|a|}_{=a}+\underbrace{|b|}_{=-b}$ since $b<-b$.
- $a<0, b>0 \overset{(*)}\implies a+b<0$. Then, indeed, $\underbrace{|a+b|}_{=-a-b}  < \underbrace{|a|}_{=-a}+\underbrace{|b|}_{=b}$ since $-b<b$.

Comment: Hi, could you extend on the second part? I'd be interested in knowing your approach. The first part is the easiest one but the second one in my case is very verbose.

Comment: @Jon just a second...

Comment: If you do the second part more straightforwardly than J.G. I will give you an upvote. Intuitively it is very easy (think of vectors that point in different directions, versus being in the same direction), so it should not require fancy operations such as squaring.

Comment: @BenjaminWang How are your thoughts now?

Comment: @Jon See the edit.

Comment: Thanks for that @VIVID. I can see that the idea is the same as my original proof but the way of writing is way better.

I feel like I'm missing the meaning of the $ (*) $, is a way to indicate that the two remaining cases where $ a > 0 $, $ b < 0 $,  $ a +b < 0 $  and $ a < 0 $, $ b > 0 $,  $ a +b > 0 $ are covered by the same principles?

Comment: @Jon Yes, you are right! It's because of symmetricity among $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Could you tell me the general name for (*)? I'd like to search more on this as I'm not very familiar with proofing and symbols

Comment: @Jon no, no, the symbol has separate and unrelated meaning to "WLOG (Without loss of generality)"! (VIVID's reply above simply explains what WLOG means) The first $(*)$ just denotes a fact that will be used later. The second and the third $(*)$ just says that "we have used the fact $(*)$ here, namely, $|a| > |b|$.

Comment: @Jon Yes, thanks to Benjamin for the explanation, indeed, that's just to label that inequality to reduce extra writing.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest some techniques for being briefer, which helps you know if you've covered all bases.

Since $|a+b|-|a|-|b|$ is unchanged when multiplying $a,\,b$ by $-1$, for the first problem we can assume without loss of generality that their common sign means they're $\ge0$, reducing the equation to the trivial $a+b=a+b$. The same invariance-under-changing-sign logic tells us the second problem only requires us to consider the case $a\ge 0>b$, whence$$(|a|+|b|)^2-|a+b|^2=a^2+b^2+2a|b|-a^2-b^2-2ab=4a|b|>0.$$

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. How do you get the 4 at the end?

Comment: @Jon it is simple addition. $2a|b| - 2ab = 4a|b|$ because $b < 0$. See my comment above. The answerer made a typo in the assumption.

Comment: Corrected now, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to J.G.'s and Bernard's answers, we have

$$(|a|+|b|)^2-|a+b|^2=(a^2+2|ab|+b^2)-(a^2+2ab+b^2)=2(|ab|-ab)=
\begin{cases}
0&\text{if }ab\ge0\\
4|ab|&\text{if } ab\lt0
\end{cases}$$

Thus $(|a|+|b|)^2=|a+b|^2$ if $a$ and $b$ have the same sign, and $(|a|+|b|)^2\gt|a+b|^2$ if $a$ and $b$ have opposite signs. Since $|a|+|b|$ and $|a+b|$ are both nonnegative, we can take the square root on both sides of things, concluding that $|a|+|b|=|a+b|$ if $a$ and $b$ have the same sign and $|a|+|b|\gt|a+b|$ if $a$ and $b$ have opposite signs.

Note, this proof uses the absolute-value identities $|x|^2=x^2$ (for real numbers $x$) and $|x||y|=|xy|$.

Added later: In answer to the OP's question, "Is my proof correct?", it's true that some cases with $ab=0$ have been ignored, but I would say that the statement of the problem itself assumes $ab\not=0$, since it talks about $a$ and $b$ having the *same* or *opposite* sign, suggesting neither one is equal to $0$, which you might say *lacks* a sign. (There is, of course, a sign *function*, which is $+1$ for positive values, $-1$ for negative values, and $0$ for $0$. But if you interpret the problem as conditioning things on whether sgn($a)=\,$sgn($b$) or sgn($a)=-$sgn($b$), then the statement is technically no longer true, since $|0+0|\not\lt|0|+|0|$ even though sgn($0)=-$sgn($0$).)